# Comparing Square Roots

Tags: inequality, roots

How do you compare square roots? Of course, the positive square root of 49 is greater than the positive square root of 36. However, what if you were to have $\pm\sqrt{49}$ ? $\pm\sqrt{36}$? Would it be $\gt$, $\lt$, or some other symbol. Also, what if you had     $\pm\sqrt{16}$ ? 0?

Comment: Usually when people say square roots, we look at the positive number - i.e. when asked for the square root of $49$, we usually say $7$ and not $-7$. But if we are asked to compare the square roots of $a$ and $b$ where $a > b$, then $\sqrt{a} > \pm \sqrt{b}$ and $-\sqrt{a} < \pm \sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only compare two real numbers. $\pm \sqrt{x}$ may be interpreted as the unordered pair $\{\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}\}$, so it is usually meaningless to compare it with something else, in the same way that it is meaningless to compare $\{1,3\}$ and $2$ or $\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. What you can say is $1 < 2 < 3 < 4$.

Comment: Not true. You can compare strings (character-by-character), arrays, and other non-numeric items. It depends on what properties you want the comparison operator to have. You can even compare answers to problems.

Comment: @martycohen: Of course I am aware of that. I just chose to focus on the problem that the asker had in understanding the meaning of $\pm$.

Comment: In fact, I did think of saying something like "If you want to make a comparison between real numbers, then you must compare real numbers.".

Comment: And if you don't want to compare real numbers, then don't.